# How do I add a fixed text before and after each item of a list in a txt file?

Tags: text-processing

Suppose I have a list of items (each item in one line) like:

```
apple
banana
grape
orange
...
...
```

I want to put some fixed text before and after each item; output `txt` file should look like:

```
SOMETEXT1
SOMETEXT2
apple
SOMETEXT3
SOMETEXT1
SOMETEXT2
banana
SOMETEXT3
SOMETEXT1
SOMETEXT2
grape
SOMETEXT3
SOMETEXT1
SOMETEXT2
orange
SOMETEXT3
...
...
```

`SOMETEXT1`, `SOMETEXT2` and `SOMETEXT3` are constant.

How can I accomplish this? Any language can be used. The list has nearly 10^7 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", "SOMETEXT1", "SOMETEXT2", $0, "SOMETEXT3"}' input-file
```

If you want to replace the current file, use `-i inplace`, with GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -i inplace '{printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", "SOMETEXT1", "SOMETEXT2", $0, "SOMETEXT3"}' input-file
```

This will work as long as `SOMETEXT*` doesn't have quotes - in which case you'll have to escape those quotes.

Comment: It works. Thanks! How can I add `SOMETEXT4` just before the original item (in the same line without spaces)?

Comment: @MoazzemHossen Try `"SOMETEXT4" $0` instead of just `$0`

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed`:

```
sed 's/^/SOMETEXT1\nSOMETEXT2\n/; s/$/\nSOMETEXT3/' input.txt
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a good candidate for the lesser-used `i` and `a` commands e.g. `sed -e 'i\SOMETEXT1\nSOMETEXT2' -e 'a\SOMETEXT3'`?

Comment: @steeldriver. Yes, that's likely faster. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your example list started with SOMETEXT3 so I wrote the example below with that in mind.

```
#!/bin/bash
sourceList=/path/to/source.list
newfile=/path/to/newfile

while read Line; do
  echo $SOMETEXT3 >> $newfile
  echo Line >> $newfile
  echo $SOMETEXT1 >> $newfile
  echo $SOMETEXT2 >> $newfile
done < $sourceList
```

Comment: [Quote your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/70524) and [use `printf` instead of `echo`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/70524): `printf "%s\n" "$SOMETEXT3" "$LINE" "$SOMETEXT1" "$SOMETEXT2"`

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```bsh
perl -ne 'print("SOMETEXT1\nSOMETEXT2\n${_}SOMETEXT3\n")' file
```

- `-n`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

  ```
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
        ...             # your program goes here
    }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program.
- `print("SOMETEXT1\nSOMETEXT2\n${_}SOMETEXT3\n")`: prints `SOMETEXT1` followed by a newline followed by `SOMETEXT2` followed by a newline followed by the current line followed by `SOMETEXT3`.

Makes sure potential special characters such as e.g. `\` and `"` in `SOMETEXTN` are escaped correctly.

To process the file in-place you can add the `-i` swith to the command:

```
perl -i -ne 'print("SOMETEXT1\nSOMETEXT2\n${_}SOMETEXT3\n")' file
```

```
% cat file
apple
banana
grape
orange
% perl -ne 'print("SOMETEXT1\nSOMETEXT2\n${_}SOMETEXT3\n")' file
SOMETEXT1
SOMETEXT2
apple
SOMETEXT3
SOMETEXT1
SOMETEXT2
banana
SOMETEXT3
SOMETEXT1
SOMETEXT2
grape
SOMETEXT3
SOMETEXT1
SOMETEXT2
orange
SOMETEXT3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/.*/SOMETEXT1\rSOMETEXT2\r&\rSOMETEXT3/|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close